# Core Data: How to test an NSManagedObjectContext merge policy

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to write a unit test for a managed object context's merge policy. According to the advanced topics section of Apple's Core Data Programming [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ChangeManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH22-SW1):

"It is possible that the same conceptual managed object will be edited in two persistence stacks simultaneously. You may want to ensure that subsequent changes made by the second stack do not overwrite changes made by the first, but other behaviors may be appropriate".

I'm using the NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy merge policy and so trying to mock having in-memory changes not override persistent store changes.

My tests involve setting up two core data stacks and two contexts both sharing the same parent context and the same merge policy. I then try to make both in-memory and store changes. How do I configure it so that in-memory changes do not override persisted changes?

```
func setUpSQLLiteMOC() -> NSManagedObjectContext? {
        let mom = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

        let fileName = String(format: "%@_%@", ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString, "TempDB.sqlite")
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: fileURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        return moc
    }

    func test_merge_policy() {
        let parent = setUpSQLLiteMOC()
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = parent
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy

        let context2 = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context2.parent = parent
        context2.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy

        var results: [SomeObject]? = nil
        var results2: [SomeObject]? = nil

        let _ = SomeObject(jsonDictionary: ["id": "user_id", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe 1"], in: context)
        let _ = SomeObject(jsonDictionary: ["id": "user_id", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe 2"], in: context2)

        context.performAndWait {
            do {
                try context.save()
                do {
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<SomeObject>(entityName: "SomeObject")
                    results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                } catch {
                    XCTFail()
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                XCTFail()
                return
            }
        }

        context2.performAndWait {
            do {
                try context2.save()
                do {
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<SomeObject>(entityName: "SomeObject")
                    results2 = try context2.fetch(fetchRequest)
                } catch {
                    XCTFail()
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                XCTFail()
                return
            }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(results?[0].name, "John Doe 1")
        results?[0].name = "John Doe 1 Edited"
        results2?[0].name = "John Doe 2 Edited"

        context.performAndWait {
            do {
                try context.save()
                do {
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<SomeObject>(entityName: "SomeObject")
                    results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    XCTAssertEqual(results?[0].name, "John Doe 1 Edited")
                    XCTAssertEqual(results?[1].name, "John Doe 2 Edited")
                } catch {
                    XCTFail()
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                XCTFail()
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now the in-memory changes are always persisting regardless of which merge policy I use.